# Request a word for believing easily because you desire to believe

Tags: single-word-requests

I find so many people on the internet who are quick to share articles as proof or quick to believe something on the internet is fact without doing research beyond said article/picture. They won't even look up the website to find if it is reputable or not. Basically they believe something is fact based solely on their desire to want it to be fact. Is there a word that describes this?

Comment: there is the term "confirmation bias" which is about when people notice "proof" that conforms with a theory they have far more often than they notice all the greater number of things that don't conform to their theory.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias

Comment: Not a word... but a common phrase: (Someone) "already drank the Kool-Aid".  Referring to the followers of the Reverend Jim Jones in Guyana who committed mass suicide (as an act of faith) by willingly drinking poisoned Kool-Aid. (US)

Answer (score 2):

**credulous** -- "Having or showing too great a readiness to believe things."  [oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/credulous)

This is not quite the same as **confirmation bias** (which might be closer to the sense you want) -- "The tendency to interpret new evidence as confirmation of one's existing beliefs or theories."  (Definition from the same source.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **to incline** (+toward) or (stronger) **to be predisposed** (+ to):

> He **inclines toward** xenophobic ideas.
>
> He is **predisposed to** xenophobic ideas.

Answer (score 0):

## trusting

adjective

> Having or exercising trust; confiding; unsuspecting; trustful.
> inclined to believe or confide readily; full of trust

Trusting in its adjective sense describes the action. It also implies the motive. But if you're looking for a less flattering way to say it you can call them gullible or say they have their head in the sand.

https://www.wordnik.com/words/trusting

Comment: Could you go back and revise your other answers too, please? Also please see our [help on answering](/help/how-to-answer) and [referencing](/help/referencing) and other stuff in the sidebar there. Wordnik is an aggregator, so you need to reference the original source.

Comment: I'll do that, thanks.